# A Four Liner of my Own: I'm counting on you

Tags: riddle, word, pattern, no-computers

With all the popularity of four liners lately, I figured I'd contribute. Since my [recent](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/the-answer-would-make-a-good-title) [riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/what-do-these-things-have-in-common) seem to have been too hard, I'll err on the side of ease this time. Determine what each line is describing (each is a single word) and what the commonality is.

> I'm depending on you.
>
> I'm lost in your eyes; there's just something about them...
>
> I'm one of many, rarely referred to individually, but just look inside and you'll find me with the others.
>
> When the previous word's done with you, come see me!

ADDENDUM: I've discovered that there is a 5th word that also shares the common bond of the previous 4. I'll add it here in the interest of making it perhaps easier on you:

> A sailor's friend, I'm the concatenation of two words (slightly ironic because the first is not known to play well with the second).

HINT:

> All 5 of the words are anagrams of each other. These words are 7 letters long each.

Comment: you call that easy?

Comment: Well it was easier originally, but some edits made before posting it on here made it harder, I realize now. I suppose I should spill the beans on the shared attribute and hopefully facilitate the solving

Comment: Are you sure that the words are 8 anagrams? The only set of 5 8-letter words that are anagrams of each other are "alerting altering integral relating triangle", which doesn't really work.

Comment: Before reading the fifth one and the hint I thought the answers are "you" (U), "eye" (I), "queue" (Q), and "see" (C), the commonality being sounding the same with a letter.

Comment: Btw, I don't think you need to put [tag:no-computer] tag here.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what tool you use. I had a program that found the first four using a dictionary text file found online. Then an online tool I used did not feature the third, but did have the fifth. Another had all five. It was at this point that I added it to the riddle.

Comment: @Runemoro: Why do you think that? I guess there are a lot more 8 letter anagramms with 5 words, why do you think there is only one? I found a site with 54 8 Letter-5 words anagramms. (and even some more then 5 words 8 letter anagramms...)

Comment: @ Runemoro Another set I could find is "restrain / retrains / strainer / terrains / trainers".

Comment: @NeedAName halp D:

Comment: It seems I made a gross error. Apparently I couldn't count when I made the hint, because the words are 7 letters long and not 8. I apologize for the wasted time on this one. I'll edit the hint accordingly for anyone still interested in solving. I assume there will be downvoting for this, which is totally fair, but want to emphasize this was an honest mistake, I didn't mean to waste anyone's time/effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha! Finally. I spent a good few days on this riddle back when it was an 8-letter word.

The answers are:

I'm depending on you.

> RELIANT

I'm lost in your eyes; there's just something about them...

> RETINAL

I'm one of many, rarely referred to individually, but just look inside and you'll find me with the others.

> ENTRAIL

When the previous word's done with you, come see me!

> LATRINE

A sailor's friend, I'm the concatenation of two words (slightly ironic because the first is not known to play well with the second).

> RATLINE

Comment: Apologies again for the incorrect information  before. Congrats on the correct answer and welcome to the Puzzling SE!